# How do i optimize this Union Query

Tags: mysql, select

I have a following query

```
    SELECT `id`,'event' as type FROM `oc_event` where `Owner_id` = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `id` ,'business' as type FROM `oc_business` where `Owner_id` = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `id`, 'parts'  as type FROM `oc_listing` where `Owner_id` = 1
```

Although, the result is accurate but its quiet slow when the number of rows fetched is around 1K or more..
Is there any kind of mysql keyword to optimize this simple query or do you thing "UNION ALL" is the right way ?

P.S : I am using PDO

Comment: Have you index on `Owner_id`?

Comment: You've order by clause in your union all query?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan No, theres no index, and I can't change the DB structure :(

Comment: @ViswanathanIyer Nope , there no order by clause.

Comment: You haven't access to DB?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan only SELECT privilege has been assigned to developer.

Comment: Then you must refer to your DB administrator.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display duplicate data then it is good to use union all
other wise use union
it will stop when a single row found 
the union_result will go faster

to make your query better create index on owner_id all the tables

Comment: Are you sure? `UNION` faster `UNION ALL`?

Comment: in my opinion yes union is good but you wont fell the difference when selecting few rows ( you can realize the use only on production environment with huge data )

Comment: Try `UNION` for nun-indexed column and `UNION ALL` then see difference in execution plan.

Comment: `UNION ALL` is usually faster than `UNION` because no sorting is required (sorting is commonly used to remove the duplicates). And as in this specific query there can never be duplicate rows unless a table has duplicates in its `id` column, using `UNION` is redundant.